# Upgrade to ubuntu 12.04 failures

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I upgraded my ubuntu to 12.04 through software center and it did not go well. The problem is I'm using this machine after a long time that I don't remember the previous version no (definitely greater than 10.0)

Machine: Asus A8ESeries

The font colors changed to white, it did not detect ext hard drives. I did an upgrade from terminal and now I get the following problems:

1. The text font color on all windows changed to white
2. The track pad did not work (Which I fixed using this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1971196)
3. Network menu not showing wireless option itself. My output for "dmesg | grep iwl" and rfkill list all are blank
4. External hard disk not detecting. I need to back up my files before upgrading again.
5. unity one launcher not working.
6. no menus at the top right corner
   and many more failures.

I really need to back up my files which is the most important task. Also get my wireless working. Please kindly help.

Regards,
psun

Comment: It is so much easier to do  a fresh install then debug a failed upgrade. I suggest something more modern like 14.04

Answer (score 0):

just do a fresh install and keep the same username and password during installation, it should save and install the packages you already have, plus it's just so much easier to iron out the kinks than debug a patchwork install. Upgrading between more than 2 versions of normal non-lts releases is really not that great to do, it works for the lts releases because they make it specifically compatible so you can jump from lts to lts